# Получить текущий url

Tags: php, url

Необходимо получить текущий адрес страницы для чего использую:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

в итоге получается:

```
/razdel/index.html
```

Как получить текущий URL страницы без названия файла, то есть без `index.html`?

Comment: [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strrpos.php)

Comment: штука в том, что я не всегда точно знаю что страница index.html или index.php

Comment: `strrpos` поможет в любом случае

Answer (score 2):

Решение рассчитано на получение пути, когда в конце есть имя файла и логика его отсекает в конце

```
<?php

$url = 'url/self/index.html';
$elements = explode('/', $url);
array_pop($elements);
echo implode('/', $elements);
```

Результат выполнения:

```
url/self
```